# How to get data from first row when 2 are output

Tags: php, mysql, bootstrap-modal

As shown in the picture I have 2 pay now buttons but how do I get data from the row and output into a modal when the button is pressed. If I do `$row['paymentAmount']` it is just going to show the last row each time. How can I correlate the button with the row so that it shows the correct amount in the modal?

[image]

```
<div class='payment_container'>
<div class='row col-md-12 custyle'>
    <table class='table table-striped custab'>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Ammount</th>
                <th>Due Date</th><?php if ($_SESSION['renterID'] == 0) {
                                                            echo "<th class='text-center'>Paid?</th>";
                                                          } else {
                                                          echo "<th class='text-center'>Action</th>";
                                                          }
                                                          ?>
            </tr>
        </thead><?php
                                        include_once 'includes/database.php';
                                        if ($_SESSION['renterID'] == 0){
                                          $sql = "SELECT firstName, lastName, paymentID, paymentAmount, paymentDate, paymentPaid FROM renter, payment WHERE renter.renterID = payment.renterID ORDER BY paymentDate ASC";

                                        } else {
                                          $sql = "SELECT firstName, lastName, paymentID, paymentAmount, paymentDate, paymentPaid FROM renter, payment WHERE renter.renterID = payment.renterID AND $_SESSION[renterID] = renter.renterID";
                                        }
                                        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                                        $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);


                                        if ($resultCheck > 0) {
                                          while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                                            echo
                                            "<tr>
                                                <td>$row[paymentID]</td>
                                                <td>$row[firstName] $row[lastName]</td>
                                                <td>$row[paymentAmount]</td>
                                                <td>";echo date ('F d, Y', strtotime($row['paymentDate'])); echo "</td>";
                                                if ($_SESSION['renterID'] == 0) {
                                                  if ($row['paymentPaid'] == '0') {
                                                    echo "<td class='text-center'><a class='btn btn-danger btn-sm'><i class='fa fa-times' aria-hidden='true'>Paid</i></a></td>";
                                                  } else {
                                                    echo "<td class='text-center'><a class='btn btn-success btn-sm'><i class='fa fa-check' aria-hidden='true'>Paid</i></a></td>";
                                                  }
                                                } else {
                                                if ($row['paymentPaid'] == '0'){
                                                  echo "<td class='text-center'><button href='#' class='btn btn-success btn-sm' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#pay_now' name='payNowID' value='$row[paymentAmount]'><i class='fa fa-usd' aria-hidden='true'>Pay Now</i></button><input type='hidden' </td>";

                                                } else {
                                                  echo "<td class='text-center'><a class='btn btn-sm'><i class='fa fa-check' aria-hidden='true'>Paid</i></a></td>";
                                                }
                                              }
                                            echo "</tr>";
                                          }
                                        } else {
                                          echo "<tr><td colspan='5'>No payments at this time</td></tr>";
                                        }
                                        ?>
    </table>
</div>
```

Thanks! Sorry if this doesn't make sense as I am very new to PHP and trying to learn.

Comment: You can do something like this `ButtonId = rowId` when button is clicked, stored the data into a new empty array then output the result in the modal.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the ID of the row where the button was clicked.

Comment: How does it know which of the 2 buttons are pressed so it can select the rownum?

Comment: set the value of ID in every PAYNOW Button based on the ID number in each row. You loop the contents of every table then get the ID then put it on ID attribute for PAY NOW.

Edit: Try to use td:nth-child for looping :)